# Unable to build G3D Library - Header not found: 'string'

Tags: c

I am following [this guide](https://casual-effects.com/g3d/G3D10/build/manual/readme.md.html) in order to compile and install G3D library.

I got this error when I try to build G3D on Ubuntu 22.04, and when I run `./buildg3d lib data tools` I got this error:

```
Building libfreeimaged.a

Computing dependencies

Header not found: 'string'.

Header not found: 'list'.

Header not found: 'map'.

Header not found: 'set'.

Header not found: 'vector'.

Header not found: 'stack'.

Header not found: 'sstream'.

Header not found: 'algorithm'.

Header not found: 'limits'.

Header not found: 'memory'.

Header not found: 'iostream'.

Header not found: 'exception'.

Header not found: 'cstring'.

Header not found: 'iomanip'.

Header not found: 'cmath'.

Header not found: 'iosfwd'.

Header not found: 'cstddef'.

Header not found: 'fstream'.

Header not found: 'cassert'.

Header not found: 'cctype'.

Header not found: 'cstdlib'.

Iterated 5 times while trying to resolve dependencies and still could not find the following headers: ['string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'iostream', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'list', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'cmath', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'fstream', 'algorithm', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'vector', 'cstddef', 'set', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'fstream', 'limits', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'map', 'string', 'sstream', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'string', 'sstream', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'fstream', 'map', 'set', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'fstream', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'algorithm', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'cstring', 'cassert', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'limits', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'limits', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstddef', 'limits', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstddef', 'limits', 'cmath', 'algorithm', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'algorithm', 'string', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'vector', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'limits', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'limits', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'vector', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'fstream', 'sstream', 'exception', 'iostream', 'sstream', 'string', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'fstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'limits', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'algorithm', 'string', 'fstream', 'sstream', 'exception', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'set', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'vector', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'vector', 'set', 'cstddef', 'fstream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'iostream', 'cstddef', 'map', 'set', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'cctype', 'cassert', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'fstream', 'vector', 'cstddef', 'set', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'set', 'string', 'sstream', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'set', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'set', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'string', 'sstream', 'exception', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'fstream', 'set', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'vector', 'set', 'cstddef', 'algorithm', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'vector', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'map', 'iosfwd', 'cstring', 'iomanip', 'set', 'string', 'exception', 'sstream', 'iostream', 'cstddef', 'vector', 'map', 'set', 'limits', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'iostream', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'cstdlib', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'exception', 'iostream', 'iosfwd', 'fstream', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'iostream', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory', 'string', 'list', 'map', 'set', 'vector', 'stack', 'sstream', 'algorithm', 'limits', 'memory']

25s

Note: build target failed with code 11
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it ?

These are the linux headers I have installed:

```
linux-headers-5.15.0-43          linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic  linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic  linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
```

Comment: Those are C++ standard library header files. Have you installed a C++ compiler and its corresponding standard library (like for example `g++`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree. Am I missing something ? Why does it blows this error ?